# How to pass arrays in custom messages

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I have a node publishing temperature data from a string of 8 batteries written in python. Each battery has 8 temperature sensors, and so rather than building a message with 64 fields I have it broken down into 8 arrays each of length 8. I have written a healthMap node in C++ and I want to subscribe to the temperature data. What should my message structure look like? Python wants to use a tuple and C++ wants a vector. Does anyone have a code example that illustrates how to approach this? I also have little experience working with vectors in C++, so hopefully you could give me a sketch of what the subscriber looks like as well.
Sorry for the long-winded question

Cheers

Gideon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11105/how-to-pass-arrays-in-custom-messages/) by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 239 on 2011-09-02

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is similar to [a previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/438/how-to-recieve-an-array-over-publisher-and). There is a good answer there that has some example code and points to [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy). The tutorial has example code for publishers and subscribers.

For [C++ vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) you can do something like the following (someone correct my C++ if I'm wrong please):

```
std::vector<double>::iterator my_iterator;
int i = 0;
for (my_iterator = msg.vector_field.begin(); msg.vector_field.end(); my_iterator++)
{
    my_local_battery_value[i] = msg.vector_field[my_iterator];
    i++;
}
```

or follow [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/33912/).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-02**:
Ignore this ... triggered the 5 comments bug.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-02**:
You could replace your code with temp = msg.temp; which would copy the vector. If that's even necessary depends on what you want to do with it.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-09-02**:
It should definitely be possible. It might even be easier than my little example code (I just haven't worked with vectors that much either).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-02**:
Well, you can also just copy the whole vector, no need for a for loop. Or ideally subscribe a shared pointer, that you store, then no copying is needed at all.

**Comment by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on 2011-09-02**:
Would this work?   for(int i = 0; i<numTemps;i++){ temp[i] = msg->temp[i]; }

**Comment by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on 2011-09-02**:
so something like this wouldnt work?

**Comment by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on 2011-09-02**:
Thanks. If my subscriber in written in C++, do I manually copy all of the fields to my local variables with a for loop?